# Even if one client port will be simple to write without it, should I still use an engine?

Tags: software-engineering

So the idea is to create a **TRUE REAL TIME** strategy game that is working as android and IOS app, and also as  web browser game. Players should be able to play on all their devices.

There will not be any physics but there will be alot of data transfering, many diferent calculations, settings. There will not be client to client direct connection, everything should go trough servers. Graphics will be simple Menus/ different pictures. Player interactions will not be graphically presented. More like raw data.

Friend's chat, team chat, Maybe global chat. Facebook/Google connection/authorization. Notifications... etc

Now after I explained the idea here are the question:

Given that the browser client will be relatively simple to write without an engine (using javascript/html/sql), should I still use a game engine to write the different clients (browser, iOS, Android); if I can avoid using an engine for one port, should I avoid using an engine at all? And, more importantly, why?

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! Your question was off-topic, I re-scoped it to try and salvage it.

Comment: From my point of view it's always better to have "one source of truth". One codebase. As otherwise as soon as you make some adjustments in lets say web you have to do it for both Android and iOS. And even more, it has to perfectly match otherwise the game will be different on different platforms which is not too nice.

Comment: @PavelStepanov That's what is bothering me. I was hoping to get information on what codebase could work this all out. Although core of the game will be server side, and really nothing important will be handled client side, only information that is given to player will be just displayed on client side. I hope that server side could be written in let's say PHP. My concern is how to pass data between server and 3 different clients and it to be safe and fast. And obviously easy to maintain and upgrade.

Comment: @Damodar You could develop your server and the clients using the same engine. Most recent and popular engines can handle in-between software instances communication and abstract all these issues for you.

Comment: You could consider [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that *one* client will be "simple" to write natively is not a good reason to not use an engine; in fact you should use an engine for all of your ports.

- One codebase to write.
- One codebase to maintain.
- One, unified, user interface for your clients.
- One way to pass data around.

The use of the engine will abstract a lot of particularities of the different platforms you'll work with. This means that you'll get the content in the hands of your users faster, in a more unified and reliable way.

Comment: I was concerned that an engine would be overkill.  Because there is only text and pictures. I was researching them before and  it looks to me that Unity would do it correctly?

Comment: @Damodar The simple fact that you target platforms like Android and iOS tell me that you should use some kind of engine. You don't want to do native dev for 3 different platform (_that_ would be overkill, IMHO). Yes, Unity is an option.

Comment: @Damodar But you should know that Unity is not your *only* option. When your game is very UI-centric, then there are better engines for that which also support wide varieties of platforms. But the system of this website here is not the best for technology recommendations.